# Detect change of resolution c# WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

is there an easy way to hook to an event that is triggered on change of global screen resolution?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Handle the following event:

```
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged
```

You may refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.displaysettingschanged.aspx) page for more details.

You may also wanna see the [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.aspx) on SystemEvents class.

Answer (score 4):

Sure you don't have to unsubscribe to static events (or any events) if your program (process) is dying. The OS will take care of releasing all memory of your process to the OS.
However, if you subscribe to a static event or to any event pointing to an object with a longer lifetime than your object subscribing, and you want that object to be eligible for GC - you need to unsubscribe (-=) to the event.

AND it is always good practice to always unsubscribe to all events. You never know when the lifetime of your objects are changed (by someone else) during the lifespan of your source code / product...

Answer (score 4):

try this simple code

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += new EventHandler(SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged);

static void SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Resolution Change.");
}
```

and don't forget this line `using Microsoft.Win32;`