# how to show complete window when screen resolution changed C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a WinForm,when the its size is 700x700,when I change the screen resolution of the system from 1366x768 to other(like 800x600),only part of the window is visible.How can I make it fully visible? what property of the form i have to change?

Answer (score 2):

I would say would say you want to adjust your `Form.Size` and `Form.Location` to fit within the `Screen.GetWorkingArea()`. You will want to do that when the event `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged` is fired. As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442337/detect-change-of-resolution-c-winforms/442368#442368).

Answer (score 0):

You will want to adjust the `Bounds` property of your form. `Screen.PrimaryScreen` can support you to get the **new** right size.