# C# how to change form and others common control PC resolution

Tags: c#

I want to change form and others common control the resolution size of PC.

sample: if PC resolution 1204.auto 1024 and other common control change.

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. Can you elaborate on exactly what you want to do?

Comment: PC resolution example: 1024*768 my software form auto change 1024*768 and next 1280*800 auto change the 1280*800.

Comment: he wants to set fullscreen in another resolution

Comment: Oh, I see :) [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/442337/464709) might be useful, then.

Answer (score 2):

Find screen height and width and assign them:

```
Screen scr = Screen.PrimaryScreen;
int newWidth = scr.Bounds.Width;
int newHeight = scr.Bounds.Height;
```

Comment: WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
            wb.Name = "web";
            wb.ScrollBarsEnabled = true;
            wb.WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled = true;
            wb.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(newWidth, newHeight);