# Windows Desktop Size changed event?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect change of resolution c# WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442337/detect-change-of-resolution-c-sharp-winforms)

I have an application written in `C#` where my window is docked to the edge of the screen.

I need to know where I can find the `event` if the `resolution has changed` so I can call the Dock method so I can repaint my window.

On the form object I can only see the `SystemColorsChanged` event.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for the [`SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.displaysettingschanged.aspx).