# How to make size of Window responsive for every type of screen resolution using Windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, screen-resolution, mdi

Make size of Window responsive for every type of screen resolution using Windows form

Comment: Did you try anything ? It is rather simple.

Comment: No but I was trying window state . maximized

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect change of resolution c# WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442337/detect-change-of-resolution-c-sharp-winforms)

Comment: This is a *very* broad question. Please read [ask]. At the very least it needs some kind of explanation as to what the form is for as that might affect different solutions suitabilities.

Answer (score 5):

It is strongly recommended using [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130(v=vs.110).aspx) because it is a much better choice for that. You can use of the `Anchor` and `Dock` properties of `Controls` on a Windows Form to achieve proper placement on different resolution but the result is not satisfactory. Also you can use [Automatic Scaling in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605(v=vs.110).aspx). However, in general WPF is much better choice.