# Object size depending on window size?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is it possible to change size of winform and then according to that change also all objects on that form?

For example I have winform where I placed some datagridview, textboxes & labels. The window is for example 800x600. And then let's say he hit MaximizeBox and winform will change size to 1600x900, I would like then make all objects bigger according to that change. I don't want to scale down, so user can't change size below 800x600.

My question is if that's even possible to scale that somehow?

Comment: Do you want the text in the controls to scale or just adjust the controls to the windows size?

Comment: You can use of the `Anchor` and `Dock` properties of Controls. But I recommended using WPF instead. check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30775012/2946329

Comment: Do take a look at how other programs handle this.  None of them ever make their text bigger, that's not what the user asked for when he maximized the window.  Making the DataGridView bigger is however sensible, he can see more rows that way, lots of ways to do that in Winforms.  Do start with a sketch of what your UI should look like at various window sizes, not thinking this through up front begets a question like this.  Otherwise easy to do, just change the form's Font property and the form's AutoScaleMode plumbing gets the job done.

Comment: @Henrik Hansen - What I exactly want is that in my app I have currently set all elements but user want to make it bigger... so he could see all things better, because currently it's to small for him. So he want to make text, and labels bigger but also all objects should change accordingly I guess so it doesn't looks bad.

Comment: @Vasquez21: OK, as other have already stated, this is not very Windowish and Winforms controls are not fit for that approach. You can do it by hand in code behind in the Form.Resize event, but it will probably get messy, because you'll have to calculate an appropriate font size every time the form is resized.

Comment: In WinForms make use of panels, they are your friend. For example make 2 panels. The first panel set Dock = top and put all labels and controls on it, the second panel set Dock = fill and put the datagridview on it, also with Dock = fill. Now you are done. This will look great no matter how you resize and is easy to maintain.

Comment: @Henrik Hansen, that's what I thought I just wanted to confirm that, I already have finished app, and I guess changing it now would be even harder than starting it all from beginning.

Comment: @GuidoG - thank you for your answer, but problem is that from what i know it will be a problem with scaling text bigger, making textboxes and buttons (also text) bigger.

Comment: Making controls (also text) look bigger is not standard behaviour you will have to do that yourself in the Resize event. This is not going to be easy. I would not rely on anchors because you have the risk of one control overlapping another. I guess you have to calculated it all yourself

Answer (score 0):

Every `control` has an `Anchor` property which can be set to follow the form's size `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y52cxte(v=vs.110).aspx

`Forms` also have a `minimum height` and `minimum width` property that will help you restrict the minimum size of the `form`.

You can do it via the designer or via code like this:

```
this.MinimumSize = new Size(800, 600);
```

Comment: Thank you Ted. I know I can set minimum size, I just add info about scalling down that I don't need scale down. About anchor it's just for anchoring and it doesn't change size, am I right?

Comment: @Vasquez21 - no you're not. anchoring also resizes the control if you do it right

Comment: @Vasquez21 - Let's say you have a `TextBox` on the Top Left of the `form`. if you set the `Anchor` to `Left`, `Top` And `Right` the `TextBox` will get longer when the `Form` is maximised. According to the number of controls in your form you may have to experiment to find the right combination of anchors so that your controls don't overlap.

Comment: oh... that's something. I will check this out, thanks.