# Windows Form Awkwardly "Resizes" when Started

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, rendering

I'm using Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017 and writing a C# Windows Form Application.

I have a windows form application that I am writing (partly in an attempt to get better at writing such things). I have designed my form nicely, with everything spaced and sized properly, but when I press F5 to start the form to debug it, I find that it loads at about 75% the size of the one I see in the designer.

This resizing seems a bit hit and miss, with buttons that were previously aligned no longer being so, and text no longer fitting in its spaces (see pic - the top part shows the designer and the bottom shows the actual form being run).

[image]

I would like to have the designer accurately reflect the final look of the form - does anyone know what is going on or how to avoid the problem? Everything I have looked at on the web talks about choosing to resize the form, not this enforced resize!

Comment: This is why, it is always recommended to use WPF to get rid of this kind of problems https://stackoverflow.com/a/30775012/2946329

Comment: This is probably related to your screen resolution/DPI settings.

Comment: Look into Form.AutoScaleMode

Comment: Can you check if your settings is 100% under
Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display

Comment: I am learning WPF as well, but this project is specifically so I learn the windows forms! Both screenshots above where taken from the same screen, which uses the recommended resolution of 1680x1050.

Comment: in the Display Control Panel I have "Change the size of text, apps and other items:" set to "100% (Recommended)"

Comment: If you make the form larger in the designer to compensate, does the result look OK then? (Just trying to figure out if it is definitely indeed scaling, which is what it looks like.)

Comment: If I make it larger, the output is larger, but the designer is still not displaying the same as the output,  button sizes are still inconsistent and the alignment is still a bit dickie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you changed the whole form  font size? By default WinForms designer set

```
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
```

try changing the AutoScaleMode and see what happens.

I've experienced similar WinForms designer issues when the default Font (in the form property) size is not 8,25pt. I dont't know why but seems related to desktop and/or screen configuration. Not sure but some weird behaviours could be bugs (WinForms is now quite old...).

AutoScaleMode.Font means that form scaling is based on font size. So trying changing different font settings can solve the problem.

hope this help

Comment: Where do I set that property - after `InitializeComponent();`?

Comment: Using each of the `AutoScaleMode` options after `InitializeComponent();` made no difference to the look of the form

Comment: What are using in design? Panels or grids? Are they off alignment off the start of the app, or when Maximized? Have you set your anchor points?

Comment: Changing the font size of the form from the (apparently default) 9.75 to 11 changes the size of the form and seems to fix a lot of the problems, even with the `AutoScalMode` set to dpi or none or whatever.

Comment: I see now! The AutoScaleMode is visible in the properties of the form itself - changing this means that the form is loaded up at the correct size; I still do not know where to write the suggested command, but changing the property of the form in the designer does the job. Please could you advise where to write the command you suggested?

Comment: Change it in the designer, it's the best choice. the "command" I wrote was just to show the designer's default.

Comment: If you are able to clarify that in your answer, I'll mark it as the official answer to help anyone else who has this problem. If not, I can write the description of what I did myself - but better if you do it!

Comment: Done! Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

When designing the form, the form automatically sets the anchor points to Top Left. You will have to set the anchor points to your form.

The anchor style works like this. On a control if you set anchor points to:

Top/Right then the control stays in the Top Right. 
Top/Left then the control stays in the Top Left. Bottom/Right then the control stays in bottom right. Bottom/Left then the control stays in bottom left.
Top then it stays at the top. 
Bottom then it stays in the bottom. 
Left then it stays in the Left. 
Right then it stays in the right. 
Top/bottom stretches top to bottom. 
Left/Right stretches left to right.

Now when you anchor a control to any of those combinations they will stay in that location when form is maximized. Controls can anchor to each other as well.

I hope this helps.

Also here is a tutorial I did on this.:

https://youtu.be/wlZ6pt79v1E

Comment: I did not know about the anchoring - thanks for the info and the suggestion! Sadly it does not seem to make a difference in this case - the whole form still resizes and everyithing in it gets a bit squashed and moved.

Comment: If your using panels, then you have set the anchor points of the panel, then the controls within the panel. I struggled with this when I first started coding. It's a common thing that novices struggle with. I am fixing to do a YouTube tutorial where I teach simplicity of Coding in C# on winform apps. The topic today just so happens to be anchor points.

Answer (score 0):

> accurately reflect the final look of the form

Your form's appearance is mostly decided by the end user. Font, size, colour, scale, contrast... all these things are under the users control, not yours.

Consider using split panels, and maybe some flow panels. Get used to 'randomly sizing' the form when you think you've finished designing, to see how it reacts to being the 'wrong size'. Someone will find a way to shrink or grow your form, and handling that gracefully is easier than enforcing a view.

Comment: I added the link to the tutorial on this exact same thing using 8 quadrant points. I hope it gives you a better understanding